# Apply formula to last cell in column

Tags: vba, excel

I know this question has been asked before but this question is slightly different, I want to search a column to get the last cell in that column with data in it (which I can do) but I want to apply a formula to the cell which is four columns over to its right. I know I can introduce a formula to a cell by doing the following:

```
Dim formul As Variant
formul -"=B25 * H25"

ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 4).Resize(1).Value = formula
```

but this is where my problem begins, I want to do something like this below, instead of setting the formula because the multiplication of the cells will always be changing when more information is being added to the sheet.

```
formul -"=ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 3).Value *      
ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, -3).Value"

ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 4).Resize(1).Value = formul
```

I need to do it like the way stated above because if I then change any information on the sheet itself it wil updat automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 4).formular1c1 = "=RC2*RC8"
```